# 条件に基づいたDUPLICATE KEY UPDATEの仕方

Tags: mysql, sql, database

MySQLのSQL文について，調べた限りだと分からないことがあり，
質問させてください。

以下のような要件でテーブルを更新するSQLを検討しています。

テーブル：

```
test_table (id INT UNIQUE,
            name char(20), 
            address char(20),
            version INT,
            other blob);
```

要件：

1. idをユニークにして，idがない時はINSERT, ある時は，そのidのレコードをUPDATE (即ち，DUPLICATE KEY UPDATEの要件そのものです。）
2. バージョン(version)に基づき，新規追加するデータのversionが既に登録済のものよりも古い場合，更新をしない。

上記を満たすSQLを検討しているのですが，なかなか綺麗に書けず，以下2点で疑問があります。

1. IFによる条件を大量に書かないといけない
   現在，IF条件を使い、下記のようなSQLで上記を満たすことができています。
   しかし，下記では同じIF部分が繰り返されており，あまり効率的とか思えません。
   また，下記の場合UPDATE自体をしていないのではなく，versionの値が古い場合は既に格納済のデータで再度UPDATEしているので，この点も効率的でないと思います。
   仕方がないのかもしれませんが，より良い実装などあれば，ご教授下さい。
   SQL文：

   ```
   INSERT INTO test_table(id, name, address, version, other) VALUES (・・・)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       name   =IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(name), name),
       address=IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(address), address),
       other  =IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(other), other),
       version=IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(version), version);
   ```
2. DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE以降の順番が入れ替わると，失敗する。
   下記，SQLの場合，otherの更新が行われません。これは，versionの値が書き換わることで，other部分のIF条件が適切に働いていないのが原因と思われます。
   ただ、今回はversionだけが条件なので良いのですが，複数の値を条件式に組み込む場合，これだと困る場合があるかなと思います。
   そもそものSQL自体がおかしいのかもしれませんが，SQLの書き方で何とかなる部分があれば，お教えいただければと思います。
   SQL文：

   ```
   INSERT INTO test_table(id, name, address, version, other) VALUES (・・・)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       name   =IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(name), name),
       address=IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(address), address),
       version=IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(version), version),  ←ここの
       other  =IF(VALUES(version) > version, VALUES(other), other);          ←入替
   ```

よろしくお願いします。